# Preg_Match filter out Attributes [PHP, XML]

Tags: php, preg-match

im trying to load a xml document and filter out every content that contains (FDS).

My Code looks like:

```
<?php
     $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://outfits.zwinky.com/users/220/287/_perverted/purchased.xml');

     $pattern = '/zwinky/fds/[^"]*';
     $subject = '$xml';
     preg_match     ( string $pattern    , string $subject    [, array $matches    [, int $flags = 0    [, int $offset = 0   ]]] )
     print_r($matches);?>
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't filter XML with preg_match, but with [XPath](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath). Try something like

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://outfits.zwinky.com/users/220/287/_perverted/purchased.xml');
$filtered = $xml->xpath('/zwinky/fds');
// do something on $filtered
```

The XPath `/zwinky/fds` *returns* all `fds` elements. The XPath for *filtering out* these elements is left as an exercise for the reader :).

Comment: It's just giving me back a empty array. Ill try around with it abit more. Thank you by the way for ur fast answers ;)